# Is the space $L^p_{\text{loc}} (\mathbb R^d)$ separable w.r.t. the norm $\|f\|_{\tilde L^p} := \sup_{x \in \mathbb R^d} \|1_{B(x, 1)} f\|_{L^p}$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, gn.general-topology

Fix $p \in [1, \infty)$. Let $(L^p (\mathbb R^d), \|\cdot\|_{L^p})$ be the Lesbesgue space of $p$-integrable real-valued functions on $\mathbb R^d$. Let ${\tilde L}^p (\mathbb R^d)$ be the space of Lebesgue measurable functions $f:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ such that
$$
\|f\|_{\tilde L^p} := \sup_{x \in \mathbb R^d} \|1_{B(x, 1)} f\|_{L^p} < \infty,
$$
where $B(x, 1)$ is the open unit ball centered at $x$.

> Is $(\tilde L^p (\mathbb R^d), \|\cdot\|_{\tilde L^p})$ separable?

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand\Z{\mathbb Z}\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}\newcommand\J{\mathcal J}$No. Consider first the case $d=1$. Let $\J$ denote the set of all subsets of $\Z$.
For $J\in\J$, let
$$f_J:=\sum_{j\in J}1_{[j,j+1)},$$
so that $f_J\in\tilde L^p(\R^d)$.
For any two distinct $J$ and $K$ in $\J$, we have $\|f_J-f_K\|_{\tilde L^p(\R^d)}\ge1$. Since the set $\J$ is uncountable,
your space $\tilde L^p(\R^d)$ is not separable. (Indeed, if $S$ is a dense subset of $\tilde L^p(\R^d)$, then for each $J\in\J$ there is some $s_J\in S$ such that $\|f_J-s_J\|_{\tilde L^p(\R^d)}<1/2$. So, by the norm inequality, the $s_J$'s must be pairwise distinct, so that the set $S$ is uncountable.)

The case $d\ge2$ is similar: then partition $\R^d$ into cubes rather than intervals.

Comment: Well $L^1(0,1)$ contains $L^\infty(0,1)$ and the first one is separable whereas it's not the case for the other one. There's something to be checked about the topology, not only set inclusion, but I would also guess that because of the supremum the space $\tilde{L}^p$ is not separable.

Comment: @AymanMoussa Agree! It's clear that there is some $C>0$ such that $\|f\|_{\bar{L}^p} \leq C\|f\|_{L^{\infty}}$. I'm not sure if the reverse inequality holds.

Comment: Oops! In my mind, I incorrectly reversed the inequality. Now this should be fixed.

Comment: I have a related question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453183/assume-fx-cdot-in-lp-textloc-y-for-a-e-x-in-x-is-f-x-to-l), I would like to ask if you can tailor your counter-example to the statement **S1** there. Thank you so much for your consideration!

Comment: @Akira : That question seems to be of a different kind, and I don't have an answer to it right now, but I will have it in mind.

Comment: Let $T>0$ and $Y := \mathbb R^d$. By axiom of choice, there is a bijection $\varphi$ from $X:=[0, T]$ onto $\cal J$. We define $g:X \times Y \to \mathbb R$ by $g(x, \cdot) := f_{\varphi (x)}$ for all $x \in X$. Here $f_J$ is as you already defined. The range of $G: X \to L^p_{\text{loc}} (Y), x \mapsto g(x, \cdot)$ is not a.e. separable. So statement **S1** (in my other thread) is not true if we can pick $\varphi$ such that $g$ is measurable...