# Is $L^p_\text{loc} (Y)$ dense in $(L^0(Y), \hat \rho)$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, measure-theory, banach-spaces, measurable-functions

Below we use [Bochner measurability](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_measurable_function) and [Bochner integral](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_integral). Let

- $(Y, d)$ be a separable metric space,
- $\mathcal B$ Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $Y$,
- $\nu$ a $\sigma$-finite Borel measure on $Y$,
- $(Y, \overline{\mathcal B}, \overline{\nu})$ the completion of $(Y, \mathcal B, \nu)$.
- $(E, |\cdot|)$ a Banach space,
- $L^0(Y) := L^0(Y, \nu, E)$ the space of $\nu$-measurable functions from $Y$ to $E$,
- $p \in [1, \infty)$,
- $L^p (Y) := L^p(Y, \nu, E)$ the space of $p$-integrable functions from $Y$ to $E$.

For $\delta >0$ and $f,g \in L^0 (Y)$, we write
$$
\begin{align*}
\{|f - g| > \delta\} &:= \{y \in Y : |f (y) - g(y)| > \delta\} \in \overline{\mathcal B}, \\
\overline{\nu} (|f - g| > \delta) &:= \overline{\nu} (\{|f - g| > \delta\}).
\end{align*}
$$

For $f, g \in L^0 (Y)$, we define
$$
\hat \rho (f, g) := \inf_{\delta >0} \{ \overline{\nu} (|f - g| > \delta)  +\delta \}.
$$

Then $\hat \rho$ is an [extended pseudometric](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Metric_space#Generalizations_of_metric_spaces) on $L^0 (Y)$. By Weierstrass [criterion](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Weierstrass_M-test#Generalization) for Banach space, we get that $(L^0 (X), \hat \rho)$ [is complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/789823/1019043). Of course, we can make $\hat \rho$ into a bona fide metric by [trimming](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3813166/1019043) and [taking quotient](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Quotient_space_(topology)#Definition) by the class of functions equal to $0$ $\nu$-a.e. For $f_n, f \in L^0(Y)$, we have $\hat \rho (f_n, f) \to 0$ [IFF](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4754273/convergence-in-a-complete-measure-is-metrizable) $f_n \to f$ [in measure](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Convergence_in_measure#Definitions).

Let $(y_n)$ be a countable dense subset of $Y$. Let $L^p_\text{loc} (Y) := L^p_\text{loc} (Y, \nu, E)$ be the space of all functions $f \in L^0(Y)$ with the norm
$$
\|f\|_{L^p_\text{loc}} := \sup_{n \ge 1} \|1_{B(y_n, 1)} f\|_{L^p} < \infty,
$$
where $B(y, r)$ is the open ball centered at $y$ with radius $r>0$. Then $L^p_\text{loc} (Y)$ [is complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4750669/the-space-lp-textloc-mathbb-rd-is-complete-w-r-t-the-norm-f) but [not separable](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452474/is-the-space-lp-textloc-mathbb-rd-separable-w-r-t-the-norm-f).

> Is $L^p_\text{loc} (Y)$ dense in $(L^0(Y), \hat \rho)$?

Thank you so much for your elaboration!